# express.static() doesn't exist

Tags: node.js

When using `express.static()` in the code below I get an error telling me that the function doesn't exist.

This is my code:

```
var app = require("express");
var consign = require("consign");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");

var express = app();
express.set('view engine', 'ejs');
express.set('views', './app/views');

express.use(express.static("./app/public"));
express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
express.use(expressValidator());

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/db.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .then('app/controllers')
    .into(express);

module.exports = express;
```

Comment: please make sure to always post questions in english here on stackoverflow or use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ if you want to post in portuguese

Comment: You're assigning the wrong thing to your `express` variable.  It should be `const express = require('express')` and `const app = express();`.  Then, you can use `express.static()` and `app.use()`.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var express = require("express"); // !!!
var consign = require("consign");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");

var app = express(); // !!!
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './app/views');

app.use(express.static("./app/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressValidator());

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/db.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .then('app/controllers')
    .into(app); // !!!

module.exports = express;
```

- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Eu falo inglês, desculpe. Eu normalmente daria uma explicação.

English: I speak English, sorry. I would usually give an explanation.